# spring MVC can not show view page(home.jsp)

Tags: spring-mvc

I got 404 error when link `localhost:8080/Project/`
I don't know why it can't show home.jsp
Please help me

message:

```
10:20:44.872 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/jsp/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
10:20:44.877 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
10:20:44.879 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
10:20:44.879 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.our.user.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.our.user.controller">
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>


   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>


   <context:annotation-config/>                                              
   <bean class="com.our.user.loginOperation.loginOperationImp"/>
```

security-context.xml

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login />
</security:http>
```

Comment: where is your jsp files are placed. is it under `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: sorry,  No,It's under ````WebContent````

Comment: in `jsp` folder under `WebContent`?

Comment: Yes,in ````jsp```` folder under ````WebContent````

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration in your web.xml file:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>
```

that will redirect to `home` page for `/` path pattern without any custom backing controller.

[Read more...](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller)

---

OR try it again without `security-context.xml` it it works then the issue is with security configuration.

Comment: I'm still not solve it with this method.  So I finally move my files under ````WEB-INF````,And it works well.Thank you!

Comment: It's good practice to keep restricted resources in WEB-INF folder to make it secure from outsider.